# BadPaddingException SOLUTION

Tags: java, android, rsa

I dont know why with the same code in android studio and netbean, the behaviour is different. I am trying to encript with RSA Algorithm in android studio and decrypt in netbean, but the decrypt doesn't work. 
It throws a BadPadding Exception, but with the same input in android the decrypt works correctly.

**Android studio** [image: https://ibb.co/6RDLVHP]

**Netbean** [image: https://ibb.co/8MgRx3r]

```
    public byte [] Encrypt(String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        byte[] encryptedBytes;

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.PublicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());

        return encryptedBytes;

    }
```

```
public String Decrypt(byte [] result) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, 
                IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        byte[] decryptedBytes=null;
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.PrivateKey);
            decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(result);
            System.out.println();
            return new String(decryptedBytes);

    }
```

Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Which version of Android?

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Decrypt' method, when you call `cipher.init(...)` you need to include a necessary 3rd parameter of type `OAEPParameterSpec`.

Documentation of the `Cipher` class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

I would suspect if you were encrypting in Netbeans and decrypting with Android Studio, you'd have the same exception occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are some incompatibilities with the way some defaults deep inside the OAEP operation are implemented on different platforms. The best way to avoid these headaches is to specify the same [`OAEPParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.html) in every `Cipher.init(...)` call, as follows:

Change

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.PrivateKey);
//...
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.PublicKey);
```

to

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.PrivateKey, OAEPParameterSpec.DEFAULT);
//...
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.PublicKey, OAEPParameterSpec.DEFAULT);
```